# To use prepositions or not?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

The sentence :

> A dog has no trouble knowing where to scratch itself to kill a flea.

I think below sentences are more familiar to my mind where a preposition comes after the trouble.

1. > A dog has no trouble **with/in/of** knowing where to scratch itself to kill a flea.

However, It seems the first sentence is a reduced relative clause. It means we can rewrite the sentence as below:

> A dog has no trouble ( that it is knowing ) where to scratch itself to kill a flea.

Under this considerations, my question is why the author preferred to use or choose reduced relative clause rather to use a preposition? If these scenarios convey different meanings in a Native person (or a person expert in English )? The sentence has been driven from an academic text. Can we say using relative clauses are more preferable in academic or formal English ?

Comment: Your third sentence makes no sense at all to me... and it sounds wrong with a preposition. Unfortunately, I don't know why. The curse of being a native speaker.

Comment: @Catija if it isn't a reduced relative clause, I am eager to know more about the **trouble knowing X**

Comment: I think you're right thinking that 'with' is omitted.  Since '*difficulty*' is a synonym to '*trouble*' in this case, you might want to look for "**difficulty *[with]* [gerund]**", I think.

Comment: In a word, _brevity_. I prefer the author's original version.

Comment: If I had to pick a preposition, I'd pick "in"... I still think it sounds better without any, though.

Comment: @J.R. **w-i-t-h** has 4 letters even **In** has two letters , Are you suggesting these 4 letters make a sentence wordy ? It is interesting. Could you explain why you prefer the original sentence ?

Comment: There's more to brevity than letter count. Concise writers strive to omit unnecessary words that add no value. It's a [*mindset*](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+extraneous+words). I have no trouble understanding the original sentence, so why add a preposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *have { trouble / difficulty / a problem } doing X* and to *have { trouble / difficulty / a problem } **with** doing X* are related expressions with somewhat different senses.

- I have { trouble / difficulty / a problem } doing X *means that it is not easy for me to do X. The subject of* have *is identical with the subject of* doing *and is always omitted.*

  > I have trouble waterboarding prisoners = *Waterboarding prisoners is difficult for me; I haven't mastered the technique.*

  In this idiom the *doing* piece is not a relative clause of any kind; it is a participle clause acting as *complement* of the noun { trouble / difficulty / a problem }  expressing what activity is difficult.
- I have { trouble / difficulty / a problem } ***with*** doing X  ***often*** (I'm going to qualify this in a minute) means that doing X *troubles me, makes me uneasy: I have practical or moral objections to doing X.* Have *and* doing *may have different subjects, and if the subject of* doing *is omitted it implies that the subject is 'generic':*

  > I have trouble with waterboarding prisoners = *For anybody to waterboard prisoners troubles me.*

  In this idiom the *doing* piece is a gerund clause acting as object of the preposition *with*. The preposition phrase *with doing X* is, again, a *complement* of the preceding noun.

  Note that this idiom may use nominals of other sorts, too:

  - I have a problem with torture of any kind.

  Moreover, the senses are so similar that the line I have just drawn is not at all a strict one. We often use the second idiom, the one with the preposition phrase, in the same sense as the first one.

  > I have trouble with solving quadratic equations.
  >   I have a problem with my eyesight.

  Which sense is intended is generally evident from the context.

  The first idiom is not, in my experience, used with the sense of the second.

Comment: I see my mistake of knowing "knowing" as a  RRC. By the Way, you are nice, bro :)